# ModuleNotFoundError When Copying a Host Directory to Container in DockerFile

Tags: docker

I'm going crazy trying to ADD a directory from my host machine to my docker container. When building the container with docker-compose up --build, it seems to ADD just fine, but when I try to access module in my app.py file, I get the ModuleNotFoundError

My DockerFile contains the following:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc musl-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev && \
    apk add alsa-lib-dev && \
    apk add pulseaudio-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add ffmpeg-dev && \    
    apk add ffmpeg && \          
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY /scraper/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD /common/testmodel /scraper/testmodel

WORKDIR home/scraper/

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-u", "app.py"]
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile - "app:app"
```

Then when building the image, the log shows:

```
Step 6/9 : ADD /common/testmodel home/scraper/testmodel
---> a7b27854d751
```

My project structure looks like the following:

```
-common
    -testmodel
        -test.py
-scraper
    -DockerFile
    -requirements
-docker-compose.yml
```

But in my app.py file, when I run `from testmodel.test import TestClass` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testmodel'`

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated as this how now taken up a much larger chunk of my day that I ever thought it would. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing some context but I think you've several issues:

- You `COPY /scraper...` and `ADD /common...` -- are these directories hanging from root on your local machine?
- You set `WORKDIR` after `COPY` and `ADD` but generally (although not required), you'd set this first as a default destination and then you could `COPY something .` and `ADD something .` and these destinations (`.`) would refer to your `WORKDIR`
- You use `/home/scraper` as your `WORKDIR` but you don't copy and add your files into it. It will be empty at this point.
- Your `ENTRYPOINT` references `app.py` but your file is called `test.py`

One useful debugging tool is to shell into containers to e.g. examine the directory structure to confirm it's as expected. Assuming your image is called `scraper`, you could:

```sh
docker build \
--tag=scraper \
--file=scraper/Dockerfile \
. # Don't forget the period ;-)
```

Then Alpine's shell is called `ash`:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive \
--tty \
scraper:latest ash
```

Or, if your `Dockerfile` has an `ENTRYPOINT`, then override it using:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive \
--tty \
--entrypoint=ash \
scraper:latest
```

and then you could browse the container's directory structure:

You'll default to `/home/scraper` (`WORKDIR`):

```sh
/home/scraper # ls -l
total 0
```

You may examine `/scraper` using:

```sh
/home/scraper # apk install tree
/home/scraper # tree /scraper
/scraper
└── testmodel
    └── test.py

1 directory, 1 file
```

I'm not entirely clear as to what would be the correct solution for you **but** I hope this helps get you progressed:

```sh
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc musl-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev && \
    apk add alsa-lib-dev && \
    apk add pulseaudio-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add ffmpeg-dev && \    
    apk add ffmpeg && \          
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR home/scraper/

COPY scraper/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD common/testmodel .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-u", "test.py"]
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile - "test:app"
```

Comment: This helps! I didn't know I could examine the project structure of the docker container with shell.  

And it seems `WORKDIR home/scraper/

COPY scraper/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD common/testmodel .` has done the trick. Thank you very much Daz!